# How to repopulate hr oracle 11g default schema

Tags: oracle11g

While setting up some jpa, by mistake i set up a `create-drop` and all the data in the default oracle schema `hr` got delete. Since i need it for a tutorial i'm following is there a .sql somewhere that can populate it back to the original ?
If i try to run `hr_popul.sql` from `oracle\product\11.2.0\server\demo\schema\human_resources` it fails to populate anything it just gives me a lot of error like these:

```
Error starting at line : 64 in command -
INSERT INTO regions VALUES 
    ( 4
    , 'Middle East and Africa' 
    )
Error report -
ORA-00001: unique constraint (HR.SYS_C007033) violated

******  Populating COUNTIRES table ....

Error starting at line : 73 in command -
INSERT INTO countries VALUES 
    ( 'IT'
    , 'Italy'
    , 1 
    )
Error at Command Line : 73 Column : 13
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00913: too many values
00913. 00000 -  "too many values"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Error starting at line : 79 in command -
INSERT INTO countries VALUES 
    ( 'JP'
    , 'Japan'
    , 3 
    )
Error at Command Line : 79 Column : 13
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00913: too many values
00913. 00000 -  "too many values"
```

Comment: It is difficult to recover objects this way, as the table structure and data-sets might be different than what was present earlier. So, It is better you seek out for other methods to restore or recreate the entire schema.

Comment: How can i recreate the entire schema ?

Comment: You should have taken backup of the database, placed it somewhere, don't you?.

Comment: Some user before left me this oracle link ( http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/hr-model30-247282.zip )is this the schema and how am i supposed to replace it ?